# Use bash to select certain gene, then count the unique variant

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

I have a tsv files that contains mutations of genes

| Gene | Mutations |
| --- | --- |
| A | Missense |
| B | Missense |
| B | Deletion |
| C | Deletion |
| D | Deletion |
| B | Silent |
| B | Deletion |

I want to:

1. Select rows with mutations of Gene B.
2. Count the unique type of mutations.
3. Count the occurrence of each type and sort it.

The output should be:

```
Deletion 2  
Missense 1  
Silent 1
```

I tried the following bash command, but it doesn't work:

```
awk '$1 == B' filename | cut -f2 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

I've tried this command based on answer provided by @jhnc and it works perfectly:

```
awk '$1=="B"{n[$2]++} END{ for(m in n)print m,n[m] }' filename | sort| uniq
```

Comment: try `awk '$1 == "B" ...`  (Also, please try to write less verbose Subject titles.) Good luck.

Comment: ... and using shell script is a good idea?  [tag:bash] += `[bioinformatics]`

Comment: assuming no escaped tabs inside columns: `awk -F'\t' '$1=="B"{n[$2]++} END{ for(m in n)print m,n[m] }' filename | sort`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am forced to do my HW with bash, so sad.

Comment: `wc` is not appropriate here but if you use `... | sort | uniq -c` you just need to reorder the columns

Comment: @AdrianTepes What does _"to do my HW"_ mean?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I mean, this is a question in my homework of course, and they asked me to finish it by bash....

Comment: @AdrianTepes Please clarify the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76186899/edit) the question.

Comment: actually, re-reading, the `wc -l` would be appropriate to use for part (2), my code only does (1) and (3)

Comment: `gawk 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" } $1=="B"{n[$2]++} END{ for(m in n)print m,n[m] }' file.tsv`

Comment: Posting data in data-table format just takes up extra space in your posting, making it harder to read on small devices. And sometime it doesn't work easily when copy/pasting into my local environment to do some testing. There may be a use case for data-table format, but I don't see it for scripting problems. Please use `{}` tool from Edit menu on mouse selected text to get good `code/data/output/Status/ErrMsgs`.  And of course only IMHO. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this (assuming the input is in /var/tmp/IP.tsv)

```
grep '^B\t' /var/tmp/IP.tsv | cut -f2 | sort -u | while read mutation; do \
 echo $mutation $( grep -c "^B\t$mutation\$" /var/tmp/IP.tsv ); \
done
```

It's not super elegant - but ....

Comment: I like our approach which are almost identical. It is more code than `perl`/`awk` sorcery, but much easier to understand for most people.

Comment: the disadvantage of looping approaches like these is that they turn O(n) complexity problems into O(m*n) which is a problem when m or n is large - instead of a single grep, you do m+1, so you do m+1 reads of an n-line file

Comment: @jhnc It indeed worked, but slow compared to your answer in comment. Anyway both will work and thank you all.

Comment: @jhnc excellent point. I always tend to make dumb solutions and if it starts to get slow then proceed to optimize. But I know many go straight with optimized algo thanks to their good expertise. Now that I'm writing code to a small mic I see how I am spoiled writing lots of unnecessary loops.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `grep -o` to filter desired output and `grep -c` to count occurrences.

This is far from a robust solution, but is not very different from your starting point and should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
for mut in $(grep -o "^B.*" input.tsv | cut -f2 | sort | uniq)
do  
    printf "%s %s\n" $mut $(grep -c "^B.*$mut" input.tsv)
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh 
Deletion 2
Missense 1
Silent 1
```

Comment: Thanks Jardel, this is helpful to create a script for further use. For my HW, I need just one sentence of code, I accept your answer and the answer provided by Mr R. Both are very helpful

Answer (score 2):

A simple command like the following will give you an output pretty close to what you wanted.

command:

```
grep B filename | sort | uniq -c
```

output:

```
  2 B       Deletion
  1 B       Missense
  1 B       Silent
```

To get your exact output, use the following command: (updated to read into three variables, thanks to jhnc. It's what i originally wanted anyways lol)

```
grep B filename | sort | uniq -c | while read i j k; do echo $k $i; done
```

To make the "grep" more robust, you can do

```
grep "^[ $'\t']*B.*" filename...
```

Comment: Yikes, 2 command substitutions (-;!? This will rank as the worst efficiency of all answers posted so far. Read comment above about `O(n) complexity`. But I like/agree with your first solution and as you are a new person, I upvote your solution. Good luck.

Comment: Talking about complexity, the sort is O(nlogn); adding a loop with O(n) does not change the complexity, even though it adds time. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: I agree it's not more complex but the constant factor is quite large because of the extra process calls. Just `... | while read n g m; do echo $m $n; done` should be faster. Input is tsv, so the more robust grep wants a tab rather than period: `'^B'$'\t'`

Comment: Ah, "read n g m" was what I was looking for. my bash skill is apparently collecting dust lol... Thanks! To make it "more" robust, we can watch out for both spaces and tabs

Answer (score 2):

A *very-very* slow on large/data input/files `bash` solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

search=B
input=file.tsv

declare -A uniq

while read -r Gene Mutation; do
  [[ "$Gene" = "$search" ]] &&
   ((uniq["$Mutation"]++))
done < "$input"

for i in "${!uniq[@]}"; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$i" "${uniq[$i]}"
done | sort
```

---

With a `grep` version.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pattern='^B '
input=file.tsv

declare -A uniq

while read -r _ Mutation; do
  ((uniq["$Mutation"]++))
done < <(grep "$pattern" "$input")

for i in "${!uniq[@]}"; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$i" "${uniq[$i]}"
done | sort
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v gene="B" '$1==gene {a[$2]++}END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' file3|sort
Deletion 2
Missense 1
Silent 1
```

Using AWK-sort

```
awk -F'\t' -v gene="B" '
  $1==gene {a[$2]++}
  END{
     n=asorti(a,sorted); 
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print sorted[i], a[sorted[i]]
}' file

Deletion 2
Missense 1
Silent 1
```